# Custom Timer Leaking Problems

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nstimer, cpu-usage

While designing an app for the iOS we needed a timer that is easily paused and resumed. Therefor we created our own timer. However, it seems to leak, causing CPU usage to build up throughout the app. Below is the entire code from the timer. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Also, we're using ARC and we're kind of new to that concept, so we might be causing a retain cycle somewhere.

```
@implementation PausibleTimer
{
    BOOL hasPausedThisCycle;
}

+ (PausibleTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
{
    PausibleTimer *newTimer = [[PausibleTimer alloc] init];
    newTimer.timeInterval = timeInterval;
    newTimer.target = target;
    newTimer.selector = selector;
    newTimer.userInfo = userInfo;
    newTimer.repeats = repeats;

    return newTimer;
}

- (void)start
{
    [self.timer invalidate]; // Invalidate current timer

    // Initialize an NSTimer with the PausibleTimer conditions
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:self.userInfo repeats:self.repeats];

    self.isPaused = NO; // Set isPaused to NO
}

- (void)pause
{
    // If the timer is currently paused, return
    if (self.isPaused)
    {
        return;
    }

    self.isPaused = YES; // Set isPaused to YES
    hasPausedThisCycle = YES; // Set hasPausedThisCycle to YES

    [self.timer invalidate]; // Invalidate current timer
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    // If the timer is currently paused, return
    if (self.isPaused)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Ignore performSelector leaks
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    if (self.selector)
    {
        [self.target performSelector:self.selector withObject:self];
    }
    else if (!self.selector)
    {
        [self invalidate];
    }
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

    if (hasPausedThisCycle)
    {
        hasPausedThisCycle = NO; // Set hasPausedThisCycle to NO

        if (self.repeats)
        {
            // Set up a new NSTimer with original timeInterval
            [self.timer invalidate];
            [self start];
        }
    }
}

- (void)invalidate
{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
    self.selector = nil;
    self.target = nil;
    self.userInfo = nil;
}

@end
```

**Update**

Here's the header file, showing the declaration of the variables. I had the target set to weak from the beginning. From what I've gathered using instruments, especially the Time Profiler, it points me to my PausibleTimer and digging deeper takes me to something called mk_timer_arm, which is supposedly still running after I have killed everything I can. Which I invalidate and set all of my timers to nil within the viewWillDisappear. Anyways, here's the header and I really appreciate your help.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PausibleTimer : NSObject

// Set up NSTimer properties
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval timeInterval;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id target;
@property (nonatomic) SEL selector;
@property (nonatomic) id userInfo;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL repeats;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer; // Pointer to current timer
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isPaused; // Check if timer is paused

// PausibleTimer initializer
+ (PausibleTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats;

- (void)pause;
- (void)start;
- (void)invalidate;

@end
```

Comment: What exactly leaks? Use Instruments to find out.

Answer (score 2):

You did not explain what is leaking, so I will give two possible considerations that arise from your code:

#### self.target

You do not show the property declaration for the instance variables, but if `self.target` is not explicitly declared `weak` then you have a retain cycle and a leak right there. Suppose we imagine a view controller or similar object that has a PausibleTimer instance variable. Then the view controller retains the PausibleTimer. But the PausibleTimer retains the view controller as its `target`. Presto, retain cycle, leak.

#### self.timer

In general, there is a big problem with NSTimer under ARC. Until it is invalidated, the timer retains its target. In this case, the target of the NSTimer is the PausibleTimer instance. So if the PausibleTimer has an NSTimer (`self.timer`) at the time the owning object (the view controller or whatever) goes out of existence, even if ARC sends `release` to the PausibleTimer in good order, still, unfortunately, the NSTimer still has a `retain` on the PausibleTimer.

#### Solution

If the second of those things is true, you have a retain cycle. If the first is also true, you have a double retain cycle.

You cannot solve this by implementing `dealloc` in the PausibleTimer to invalidate the NSTimer, because `dealloc` won't be called; that is the whole problem. Similarly, you cannot solve this by implementing `dealloc` in the view controller to invalidate the PausibleTimer, because (again) `dealloc` won't be called; that is (again) the whole problem.

Basically you have taken what is already a memory management problem with NSTimer and pushed it back one stage, in a way that probably aggravates it.

The way I solve this with a normal NSTimer owned by a view controller is that I explicitly `invalidate` the timer *before* the view controller goes out of existence, e.g. in `viewWillDisappear:`. This causes the NSTimer to release its target, which can later go out of existence in good order. You will presumably have to do something like that.

Comment: And see my discussion of memory management problems with NSTimer under ARC here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_unusual_memory_management_situations

Comment: And here is example code that demonstrates the NSTimer problem and some solutions: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch12p352timerLeaker/ch12p325NotificationLeaker/FlipsideViewController.m